# Create a Dictionary from Arrays of Keys and Values

Tags: julia

I have:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "j"]
vals = [1, 42, 9]
```

and I want something like:

```
somedic = ["a"=>1, "b"=>42, "j"=>9]
```

i.e.

```
Dict{String,Int64} with 3 entries:
"j" => 9
"b" => 42
"a" => 1
```

But how??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Keys & Values to Dict**

```
ks = ["a", "b", "j"]  # keys
vals = [1, 42, 9]     # values
thedict = Dict(zip(ks, vs))
```

```
# or using broadcast syntax, which looks quite nice IMO (though 
# does create a temporary Vector of key=>value pairs)
thedict = Dict(ks .=> vals)
```

The returned Dict will be of type `Dict{String, Int}` (i.e. `Dict{String, Int64}` on my system), since keys is a Vector of `String`s and vals is a Vector of `Int`s.

---

**Specifying the Types**

If you want to specify the types of the Dict's keys or values, e.g. `AbstractString` and `Real`, you can do:

```
Dict{AbstractString, Real}(zip(ks, vals))
```

---

**Related aside: Pairs in a single Vector/Array**

If you have pairs in a single array:

```
dpairs = ["a", 1, "b", 42, "j", 9]
```

you can do:

```
Dict(dpairs[i]=>dpairs[i+1] for i in 1:2:length(dpairs))
```

the same syntax as above applies to specify the respective types of the keys and values, e.g.:

```
Dict{Any, Number}(dpairs[i]=>dpairs[i+1] for i in 1:2:length(dpairs))
```

Comment: Could you update your answer with zip? I got deprecated warning. `WARNING: Dict{K,V}(ks::AbstractArray{K},vs::AbstractArray{V}) is deprecated, use Dict{K,V}(zip(ks,vs)) instead.`

Comment: @Aung Done, cheers : ) (I actually did it years ago, but forgot to say thanks - so thanks! :))

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Julia -- but if Julia has a `zip`, then this should work : `dict(zip(keys,vals))`.

(confession: this is how one would do it in python).

Answer (score 0):

I think the Julian way would be to use the vectorized `.=>` version

```
keys = ["a", "b", "j"]
vals = [1, 42, 9]
Dict(keys .=> vals)
```

This is equivalent to using `broadcast(=>, x, y)`

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-and-vectorized-operators-and-functions